# What command line can i use to create a script that will print a smiley in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have tried this line of code but it is not working.
`#!/bin/bash`
`echo $\'U+1F615'`

Comment: Can't you just put `echo ''` in your script? It's probably a lot easier to maintain if you can actually see the smiley in the code too.

Comment: Why is this tagged Powershell, when you are using bash? Running bash from PowerShell does not make it PowerShell code. You are confined to the tool features as documented. There are many articles on using emojis in Powershell. Using your favorite search engine you can discover them. for example [Powershell Emojis And How To Display Them](https://www.powershellcenter.com/2021/02/19/add-emojis-to-powershell-output/)

Comment: `$\'U+1F615'` is clearly a typo; did you mean to put the backslash _after_ the opening quote? The correct syntax would lose the `+` too; `echo $'\U1F615'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two versions:

```bash
printf '\U1F615\n'      # or: echo -e '\U1F615'
```

or actually putting the smiley in the code:

```bash
printf '\n'           # or: echo ''
```

Comment: Stylistic cringe for preferring `echo -e` over `printf`

Comment: @tripleee I change easily :-)